# Unneccessary rebuilds because .lo files are not found

Tags: makefile, autotools, libtool, buildroot

Has anyone seen something like this:

when running make in a project using autotools, it always rebuils everyhing. Running with make -d, shows that make looks for foo.lo files and because they are not found, always recompiles foo.c.

It seems to be related to builddir != srcdir.
The .lo files are of course in the builddir. But apparently make or libtool are expecting them somewhere else:

Debug output lookgs like this:

Prerequisite `/path/to/srcdir/foo.h' is older than target`foo.lo'.
      /path/to/builddir/.deps/foo.Plo:1   Must remake target `foo.lo'.

**Update** It seems the problem is caused by AC_PROG_LIBTOOL. According to the documentation it expects a variable called top_builddir to be set to the builddirectory. What is the standard way to set it? Is there a autoconf macro for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A libtool update solved this problem